# How to add the footer for the p-dropdown in primeng?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, primeng

I am trying to add a `p-dropdown` footer similar to a multiselect but it is not working.

```html
<p-dropdown [options]="genes" formControlName='geneId' appendTo="body">
    <p-footer>
        <button type="button" pButton  iconPos="right" icon="pi pi-fw pi-chevron-right" label="Create New Gene" ></button>
    </p-footer>
</p-dropdown>
```

The dropdown is not showing using the above code, but it is working in the `multiselect` shown below. I want to do this with the dropdown.

```html
<p-multiSelect [options]="genes" formControlName='geneId' appendTo="body" [selectionLimit]="1">
    <p-footer>
        <button type="button" pButton  iconPos="right" icon="pi pi-fw pi-chevron-right" label="Create New Gene" ></button>
    </p-footer>
</p-multiSelect>
```

How do I create the footer for the p-dropdown.?

Comment: Please share demo in https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

p-dropdown component doesn't support add a footer section but  we can manage to fake a footer section like this

```
<p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" [options]="cities1" appendTo="body" #dd>
        <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item" >
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="position: relative;height: 25px;">

          <button *ngIf="option.value == 0; else selecteItem" 
              type="button" pButton  iconPos="right" 
              icon="pi pi-fw pi-chevron-right" 
              label="Create New Gene" 
              (click)="handler();dd.hide()">
          </button >

          <ng-template #selecteItem>
            <div style="font-size:14px;">
              {{option.label}} 
              </div>

          </ng-template>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

> you can set your own condition may be base of the label also `option.value == 0`,dd.hide() is related to p-drowndown to hide the option list

component

```
  handler() {
    // show create dialog 
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ls1xe1-3daday)